# Flex Row with Expansion Panel spacing issue

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-material

I am having a problem with the spacing of expansionpanels inside a flex row

I have multiple `Mat-Expansion-Panel` inside an `ngFor` inside there are multiple items, and every panel has different item length.

Now when I expand one panel, the one beside it will also expand to the same height but without showing the item (since its not really expanded)

[image: flex with panels]

I have created a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-expansion-panel-x8qz9z

Since my panellist is a seperate component and is used multiple times with different layout, do I really need to make 2 seperate columns inside the `*ngFor` to make this work?

Edit1: I have tried `height:max-content` on `the mat-expansion-panel` but the problem is panel 3 should move up under panel one.

The same problem exists for `align-items:baseline;` on the container

[image]

Kind regards

Comment: add `height: max-content;` to `mat-expansion-panel` to fix it

Comment: just tried it somehow works better but still not exactly what I want, see the updated question

Comment: What about ```.panel-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: baseline;
  height: 400px !important;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 !important;
}```

Comment: @stackg91 if you want two independent columns, you have to make two independent lists

Comment: @FatemeFazli this does seem to work but the number of panels is not fixed since I am getting this data from the backend so I dont know how many groups i could only calc the container height by the count of panels i get from the response maybe.

Comment: @FatemeFazli also your approach breaks when I open 3 panels at the same time which is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can only be done with 2 separate columns. You can split your array into two columns, or however many you may need like this:

```
columns = [
  this.panels.slice(0, Math.ceil(this.panels.length / 2)),
  this.panels.slice(Math.ceil(this.panels.length / 2))
];
```

You can use this array in your template:

```
<div class="panel-container">
  <div class="panel-column" *ngFor="let columnPanels of columns">
    <mat-expansion-panel class="panel" *ngFor="let panel of columnPanels">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        {{panel.name}}
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>

      <div *ngFor="let item of panel.items">{{item}}</div>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
  </div>
</div>
```

And update your css:

```
.panel-container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}

.panel-column {
  flex: 1;
}

.panel {
  margin: 10px;
  height: max-content;
}
```

[stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-expansion-panel-k9ddlp)

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is probably the best / cleanest way to solve this, although this creates many problems regarding my model bindings and the usage of my component in the other implementations :(.